# Angular 2 - Possible to subscribe to http errors in the 'calling' component?

Tags: http, angular, reactive-programming

I'm having trouble retrieving the error from the service.
My component is calling a service and I want to subscribe to any errors that might be returned. However, it seems like I'm not allowed to subscribe on the calling method.

```
public getMethods(v) {
    if(v != null) {
        return this._http.get('http:localhost/testservice', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers([
                'Accept', 'application/json',
                'Content-Type', 'application/json'
            ])
        })
        .map(res => (res.json()))
        .map((method: any) => {
            if(method) {
                let result: Array<string> = [];
                var list = method.List;

                list.forEach(v => {
                    result.push(v);
                })
                return result;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(data => {
            this._dataStore.mn= data;
            this._mnObserver.next(this._dataStore.mn);
        },
        error => {
            **// I want to retrieve this error in the 'calling' component**
            return error;
        });
    }
    else {
        console.error("Get names. V was null");
    }
```

In the component:
This does not work:

```
this._mnService.getMethods(v), error => {
      alert("error in da house");
};
```

This does not work:

```
this._mnService.getMethods(v).subscribe( error => {
      alert("error in da house");
});
```

So, what would work?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor a bit your method:

```
public getMethods(v) {
  if(v != null) {
    return this._http.get('http:localhost/testservice', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers([
            'Accept', 'application/json',
            'Content-Type', 'application/json'
        ])
    })
    .map(res => (res.json()))
    .map((method: any) => {
        if(method) {
            let result: Array<string> = [];
            var list = method.List;

            list.forEach(v => {
                result.push(v);
            })
            return result;
        }
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Get names. V was null");
  }
}
```

This way you will receive the error when subscribing on the observable:

```
this._mnService.getMethods(v).subscribe((data) => {
  }, error => {
    alert("error in da house");
  });
```

What is a bit strange in your code is that you subscribe in the `getMethods` method. So you don't return an observable for the request but a subscription.

If you want to trigger the `_mnObserver` when the response is there, you could leverage the `do` operator instead. Here is a sample:

```
public getMethods(v) {
  if(v != null) {
    return this._http.get('http:localhost/testservice', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers([
            'Accept', 'application/json',
            'Content-Type', 'application/json'
        ])
    })
    .map(res => (res.json()))
    .map((method: any) => {
        if(method) {
            let result: Array<string> = [];
            var list = method.List;

            list.forEach(v => {
                result.push(v);
            })
            return result;
        }
    })
    .do(data => { // <-------
      this._dataStore.mn= data;
      this._mnObserver.next(this._dataStore.mn);
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Get names. V was null");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, so is it a bad practice to use subscribe inside the service? I've been using examples from different places, eg. https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services
Would there sometimes be preferable to subscribe inside the service?

Comment: No it's not a bad practice but it depends on what you want to do ;-) But you need to be careful when subscribing several times. For example with a cold observable (an observable that can't be shared) like ones from HTTP, corresponding requests will be executed several times (the times you subscribed). You need: `this._http.get('http:localhost/testservice').share();`. In your case, the problem was that you subscribe in the service and return the subscription  (what subscribe returns) and not the observable itself...